# how to stream audio files in android

Tags: android

I am trying to stream audio files in android but everytime I get this exception

java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1

for my songs url stored on the server. eg([http://Touchstoneesol.com/listen/ML1 (Section 2).mp3](http://Touchstoneesol.com/listen/ML1%20(Section%202).mp3));

But same code stream this link properly (http://android.programmerguru.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/hosannatelugu.mp3);

Now I am stuck inbetween whether there is some problem in the code or my songs link is corrupt.

```
buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try {
                mPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mPlayer.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            mPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can test here : http://demo.jwplayer.com/stream-tester/   if your stream links are working .

Comment: Thank you  , issue removed , make sure to remove the empty spaces in url.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class StreamAudioDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
OnPreparedListener, OnErrorListener, OnCompletionListener {

    MediaPlayer mp;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
    bt.setOnClickListener(this);
}

   @Override
   public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
       Log.i("StreamAudioDemo", "prepare finished");
       pd.setMessage("Playing.....");
       mp.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
       try
        {
            pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pd.setMessage("Buffering.....");
            pd.show();
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
            mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
            mp.setDataSource("http://www.robtowns.com/music/blind_willie.mp3");
            mp.prepareAsync();
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("StreamAudioDemo", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
      pd.dismiss();
      return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        pd.dismiss();A
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();     
    }
}
```

This is the xml that contains the button.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<Button 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Stream Audio and Play"
    android:id="@+id/play"
    />
</LinearLayout
```

Comment: Thank you Akshay for suggestion, infact I found the solution . The problem is coming because of space in my url.